# Getting legend in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, legend

I'm new to the geoserver. I want to add legend in the map. I've no any idea that how to do it. Please help me. Here is my sld file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" version="1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <NamedLayer>
    <se:Name>Province_Boundary</se:Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <se:Name>Province_Boundary</se:Name>
      <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>Gandaki Province</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>Gandaki Province</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>PRO_NAME</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>Gandaki Province</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#cf9a43</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>Karnali Province</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>Karnali Province</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>PRO_NAME</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>Karnali Province</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#b5f04f</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>Province 1</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>Province 1</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>PRO_NAME</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>Province 1</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#5586da</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>Province 2</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>Province 2</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>PRO_NAME</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>Province 2</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#d46876</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>Province 3</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>Province 3</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>PRO_NAME</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>Province 3</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#7c3ce4</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>Province 5</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>Province 5</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>PRO_NAME</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>Province 5</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#df7dd2</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>Sudur Paschim Province</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>Sudur Paschim Province</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>PRO_NAME</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>Sudur Paschim Province</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#37cbba</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:TextSymbolizer>
            <se:Label>
              <ogc:PropertyName>PRO_NAME</ogc:PropertyName>
            </se:Label>
            <se:Font>
              <se:SvgParameter name="font-family">Ubuntu</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="font-size">13</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="font-weight">bold</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Font>
            <se:LabelPlacement>
              <se:PointPlacement>
                <se:AnchorPoint>
                  <se:AnchorPointX>0</se:AnchorPointX>
                  <se:AnchorPointY>0.5</se:AnchorPointY>
                </se:AnchorPoint>
              </se:PointPlacement>
            </se:LabelPlacement>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:VendorOption name="maxDisplacement">1</se:VendorOption>
          </se:TextSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
      </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

something like this

[image]

in the layer preview windows.
[image]

Comment: GetLegendGraphic >> https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/get_legend_graphic/index.html

Comment: Thanks for your help but it is not clear how to use, where to use, I'm searching somethings like working example, or some guide which help me to implement this.

Comment: layout is added to GeoServer (legend.xml to be placed in GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR/layouts use your code).

Comment: If you do a WMS GetCapabilities request on your service, the response will tell you the URL for the legend through a GetLegendGraphic request for your layer and style combination.

Comment: did you manage ? i am with the same problem, not sure where to insert the code to getlegend or what to change in the layout xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for what GeoServer calls a [`Decoration`](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/decoration.html) - you need to create a `layout` file in a subdirectory called layouts in the GeoServer data directory as XML files, one file per layout. Each layout file must have the extension .xml. Once a layout foo.xml is defined, users can request it by adding &format_options=layout:foo to the request parameters.

Layout files follow a very simple XML structure; a root node named layout containing any number of decoration elements. The order of the decoration elements is the order they are drawn so, in case they are overlapping, the first one will appear under the others.

For a legend such as you seek, something like this:

```
<layout>
    <decoration type="legend" affinity="top,right" offset="6,6" size="auto"/>
</layout>
```

Comment: how can I change font family for the legend?

Comment: looking at the [code](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/master/src/wms/src/main/java/org/geoserver/wms/decoration/LegendDecoration.java) it doesn't seem possible. You would need to use a `getLegendGraphic` request to control that